# How to pass a List to a model and later on Binding to Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to get the complete list of players to display on Home Page, below the line of code displays a single record

`var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();`

Is this problem with my code or Home.xaml ? I have tried

```
playermodel = details[0];
playermodel = details[1];
playermodel = details[2];
```

but still gives the only a single record.

My `Home.xaml` given below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="White" Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="gridDisplay" Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Use Grid.Column to specify column -->

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FullName}" BackgroundColor="#92f459"/>
            <Label x:Name="HomeLabel"  Text="Home Page is here" TextColor="White"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Small"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Below is my `Home.xaml.cs`

```
namespace soccerapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Home : ContentPage
    {
        public SQLiteConnection conn = null;

        public Home(string parameter1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
            conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
            DisplayDetails();
        }

        public void DisplayDetails()
        {

            var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
            PlayerDetails playermodel = details[0];
            gridDisplay.BindingContext = playermodel;
        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: your query appears correct - if you are only getting a single record it probably means there is only one record in your table

Comment: No Jason, there are two more records available, I am not sure if my Grid in  'Home.xaml' is correct to display all players ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  If you want to bind a collection to a grid, you need to use bindable layouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Comment: Tried with `<Grid BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />` as per above link. But it doesn't work

Comment: As per my question, how do we push the `details` into the `playermodel'` and then bind to the Grid layout. Is my Home.xaml layout is correct /looking good ?

Comment: in Xamarin forms grids are used for design page layout. you should use ListView to show list of contents

Comment: But I would like to show the contents in Grid not as normal list, so is that possible with ListView?

Comment: you need to re-read the post I linked to.  Using a BindableGrid also requires you to provide a DataTemplate, have you done that?  And based on your code above your DisplayDetails ALWAYS binds a single row to the grid, so you will never see data for more than one player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your `xaml` code and use `collectionView` to achieve your requirement.

In your `Home.xaml`,I use a collectionView to show data of players, you can Add other labels to show other data in `DataTemplate`. If you want to change the number of items per line, just change the  value of `Span`:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="playerTemplate">
        <ContentView>
            <StackLayout  Margin="10,10" BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" />

                <Label Text="{Binding Mobile}" />

                <!--Add other labels here to show want you want to show--> 

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>


</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionview"

             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource playerTemplate}" >


        <!--span here decides the number of items shows in one line. Now is 3 items one line-->
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

In your code behind, every time you get data, set it to the `itemSource` and it will change in the `collectionView`:

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn = null;
    public PlayerDetails playermodel;

    ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails> players;

    public Home(string parameter1)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
        conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
        players = new ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails>();

        collectionview.ItemsSource = players;

        DisplayDetails();
    }

    public void DisplayDetails()
    {

        List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
        {
            players.Add(details[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Refer: [collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/)

Here is the result:

[image: Players]

**Update:**

> CollectionView is available in the Xamarin.Forms 4.0 pre-releases.
>   However, it is currently experimental and can only be used by adding
>   the following line of code to your AppDelegate class on iOS, or to
>   your MainActivity class on Android, before calling Forms.Init:

```
Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

Comment: Sorted that `collectionview` context error..but now while navigating to home it throws error at this step `InitializeComponent();`  with following error details`System.InvalidOperationException: The class, property, or method you are attempting to use ('VerifyCollectionViewFlagEnabled') is part of CollectionView; to use it, you must opt-in by calling Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental") before calling Forms.Init().`

Comment: Hua Thank you very much for your reply. Appreciate your effort.Is CollectionView an experimental version ? I am getting the above error at the `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: @soccerway See my edited answer, add that line to MainActivity  in Android and AppDelegate in iOS before calling Forms.Init.

Comment: Thanks, I have added that, but it shows ` the type or namespace 'SetFlags` doesn't exist in the namespace Xamarin.Forms `

Comment: I have added like below:
          `Xamarin.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
            InitializeComponent();`

Comment: @soccerway No, you added at a wrong place. Put it in **MainActivity** in Android.project.

Comment: I have added in `MainActivity.cs` in android project, now the error has gone and navigating to home page displays blank

Comment: @soccerway Can you see the data in details?

Comment: Yes, I can see 5 records are getting at this point while setting a break point :` var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();`

Comment: @soccerway Can I check your code? Hard to know where the problem is without seeing any code.

Comment: @Hua I have added the <a href="https://gitlab.com/k.vinodmathew/k-vinodmathew">GitlabLink</a>

Comment: @soccerway Try my edit. I changed the code in `DisplayDetails()`.

Comment: This is working fine, what was the problem in earlier code ? How does it work for you ?

Comment: @soccerway I didn't use the data from database on my side. I create some temp playerDeatils models when I test so it may caused by the players has been initialize again in earlier code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this the Flex-Layout

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adaptive-mobile-designs-with-flexlayout/